# This tweepy code are not working .Provide 'API' object has no attribute 'trends_place' Error

Tags: python, web, tweepy

This code is not working.

The error shown is `Provide 'API' object has no attribute 'trends_place' Error`

```py
import tweepy

# Authenticate to Twitter
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(
    "consumer_key", "consumer_secret",
    "access_token", "access_token_secret"
)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
woeid = 1 # For global trends
trends = api.trends_place(woeid)

for trend in trends[0]["trends"]:
    print(trend["name"])
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. To make things run more smoothly, please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) of how SO works and especially [How To Ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then please edit your question with more detail so others could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the [official tweepy documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html) under the [Trends section](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#trends),

*Changed in version 4.0: Renamed from API.trends_place*

So maybe you are using version 4.0 of the tweepy module, you can check using

```
pip show tweepy
```

So, if you are using version 4, the new method is called **get_place_trends**